# connecting bluetooth audio sink to PiFmAdv

Tags: pi-3, audio, pulseaudio, pifm

I have a raspberry pi configured as a bluetooth audio sink using this post: 
[Another How to turn your Pi in a Bluetooth Speaker Tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=235519). Which uses pulseaudio.

I also have the PiFmAdv configured and working from wav files.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the audio from `pulseaudio` to `pifmadv`.

I know on the `pifmadv` side I can pipe audio to it using this: `| sudo ./pi_fm_adv --audio -` 
But I can not figure out how to get an audio pipe out of pulseaudio.  I tried `cat` on the `/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p` file but that didn't produce any results.

In my research it seems that audio is treated differently and can't just be gleaned from the device files.
How can I get the audio from pulseaudio into a pipe?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Bluetooth is an audio output system. PiFmAdv (which is illegal in countries with a regulated radio spectrum) is an audio output system. You're trying to connect two outputs together, where's your audio source?

Comment: @Dougie Check out the first part of the post. It explains how its an audio **sink**.

Comment: @Dougie I'm sure your thoughts are in the right place, but please resist the urge to tell someone how what they are doing is illegal unless you know it to be a fact.  For radio broadcast, how do you think these things are developed in the first place? For the US you can read up on it on the FCC website.